# How is the return value interpreted in assembly function called from C in dsPIC33?

Tags: c, assembly, microcontroller, microchip, dspic

I have just started into RTSP and was looking at the assembly code in Microchip's RTSP examples. There are two files `rtsp_api.h` and `rtsp_api.s`. I wanted to know how are the return values fetched and how does that work.

For example, there is a function in `rtsp_api.h` which is declared as follows

```
/******************************************************************************
     * Function:        int16_t FlashPageRead(uint16_t nvmAdru, uint16_t nvmAdr, int16_t *pageBufPtr);
     *
     * PreCondition:    None
     *
     * Input:            nvmAdru - Selects the upper 8bits of the location to program or erase
                                    in program flash memory

                         nvmAdr  - Selects the location to program or erase in program flash
                                   memory. It must be aligned to 512 instruction boundary,
                                   LSB 10bits of address must be zero
                         pageBufPtr- Pointer to the data array in which read data will be stored

     *
     * Output:           Function returns ERROREE (or -1), if it is not successful,
                         Function return ZERO, if successful
     *
     * Side Effects:    None
     *
     * Overview:        This function provides the interface to read the flash.
     *****************************************************************************/
    int16_t         FlashPageRead( uint16_t nvmAdru, uint16_t nvmAdr, int16_t *pageBufPtr );
```

and its definition in `rtsp_api.s` is as follows

```
/******************************************************************************
  Flash Page Read 
  Read EIGHT rows (PAGE) of memory, upper PM byte is discarded
*******************************************************************************/
_FlashPageRead:
        push    TBLPAG
        mov     w0, TBLPAG
        mov     #1024, w3

readNext:     
  tblrdl  [w1],[w2++]
  tblrdh [w1++],w6  ; Discard PM upper byte
        dec     w3, w3
        bra     nz, readNext

  clr  w0
   pop     TBLPAG
        return
```

The code documentation says that the function returns -1 on failure.

Refering to the [X16 Compiler User Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MPLAB%20XC16%20C%20Compiler%20Users%20Guide%20DS50002071.pdf) section 13.8.2, I saw that the return valus are kept in W0 Register, but the code above clears the W0 register before returning.

Then how would the code return -1 ? Could this be a bug or is it my extremely limited knowledge of assembly ?

Comment: Maybe the statement 'returns  -1 on error' is generic for many functions. And there is no chance FlashPageRead() could fail, so it returns always SUCCESS.

Comment: Maybe, even the datasheet, flash programming manual and other documents do not mention anything about the read failing.